# How does Molten Core affect turrets?

Tags: overwatch

I got several conflicting sources

1. It starts with level 1. Then you hit it 6 times, it becomes level 3.
2. It starts with level 2. Then you hit it 6 times, it becomes level 3.
3. If  you create a level 1 turret and then turn on molten core, that level 1 turret becomes level 2 and you hit it 6 times, then it becomes level 3. If you activate molten core and then build a turret then it will start at level 1 you hit it 6 times and it becomes level 2.

Which of the 3 scenario is right?

Should I build a level 2 turrets and turn on molten or should I drop a level 1 turret turn on molten and quickly upgrade, or should I turn on molten and turn on turrets?

Answer (score 4):

Molten Core upgrades level 2 turrets to level 3. It does nothing to level 1 turrets. Of your cases, number 1 is correct.

Incidentally, the Practice Range exists exactly for this kind of doubt about game mechanics.

Comment: Motel core kinda helps level 1 turrets as well. Sometimes it's a good strategy (When you need to defend the point but have just died and haven't had time to setup your turret for instance) to actiavet Molten Core, and then place and upgrade a turrent. The upgrade will occur much faster because of the increased attack speed of the hammer.

Comment: Hey @Wrigglenite, is this answer still valid with the overhaul to Molten Core discussed in the [October Patch notes](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/news/patch-notes/pc/?page=2#patch-51575)?

Comment: @Robotnik I didn't even know Molten Core was changed, so I'm afraid I'm not qualified to answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

## How it works

Molten core (**MC**) instantly upgrade your lv2 turret in lv3.
If you have a lv1 turret it doesn't upgrade  to lv2, you have to hammer it.

### What should you do?

Well, try to keep your turret always lv2, so you are ready to **MC** it to lv3.

If you turret get destroyed and you have **MC** ready, you can do 2 things, depending on the situation:

1. You have the space and time to build and upgrade, the enemies cannot focus on you. In this case you can build up and use molten core when they push again, keep the CD ready for them.
2. Enemies are already pushing and they keep destroyng your lv1 turret. Now it's the time to be brave. **MC**, place yourself between the enemies and your turret, build the turret protecting it with your body (and build it fast with the improved attack speed).

OW is a very dynamic game, keep playing and get into more and more complex mechanics :)